# Google Closure Lib Db Connection

Tags: database, google-closure

I'm working with Google Closure Lib, but I'm lost about the connection with a db.

Comment: Are you using closure for server side code like node.js or to run in a browser (client side code)? If it's for client side code then how would you connect to a database? I assume the database is on the server so you would like client side JS code connect to your server. Any client can read your code and see the connection parameters (server, user, password). This is only hipathetical because client side JS in browser cannot connect to a db, you can call server side code such as PHP with AJAX calls.

Comment: If you would like to build a desktop application with DB connection using JS some of your options are Adobe AIR: the flex framework with flashdevelop free IDE to create AIR apps (windows only), XULRunner and Rhino but I haven't any experience with the last 2.

Comment: Thx @HMR for your answers. I had been reading tutorials and my conclusion is that the php way could be my better option.